# How to append elements into dom in one go

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I append elements into the dom in one go? As you can see from the code below I'm appending stuff into a root element(tr_next) inside a loop.

```
$('.abc').each(function(){
  //create element code here
  var tr_next = $("<tr>");
  var td_contact_fname = $("<td>").attr({"width" : "190px" , "align" : "center"});

  td_contact_fname.appendTo(tr_next);
  td_contact_lname.appendTo(tr_next);
  td_month.appendTo(tr_next);
  td_day.appendTo(tr_next);
  td_email.appendTo(tr_next);
});
```

I've watched this video at vimeo: [How browsers work internally](http://vimeo.com/44182484) and they said that when appending stuff into the dom you should do it in one go because the browser needs to perform a lot of repainting(or something like that) which affects performance.

Comment: each is a loop which is done in one go. so there's nothing more to be done

Comment: Could you include your assignment of `tr_next`?

Comment: @rjz: added. That's pretty much what I'm doing for the rest. Maybe there's something that I could do to gather everything that's on the loop and then append that one outside of the loop.

Comment: yes, you can do it, lemme give it a shot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jQuery Fundamentals](http://jqfundamentals.com/#chapter-9) has some handy guidelines about this.

Loops like your sample and what ends up happening with 'append(item1,item2)' are the slowest.

You might want to create a document fragment, append everything to that and then after the loop is complete, append the fragment to the body:

```
   var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
   $('abc').each(function() {
      frag.appendChild(/*Stuff you want to append */);
   }
   $("<tr>").appendChild(frag);
```

Or use the loop to build a string of html and append like so

```
 $('<tr>').html(myHtmlString)
```

Answer (score 5):

The `.append` function can accept multiple jQuery objects as arguments:

```
tr_next.append(td_contact_fname,td_contact_lname,td_month,td_day,td_email);
```

Whether this actually performs all appends with a single operation, I'm not sure, but if there is a way to optimize multiple appends, I would assume that the jQuery team has implemented it.

At the least it will clean up your code.

Comment: they said something like gathering everything that you need to append and then append it at once. I don't know how to do that. Is this more performant?

Comment: @Kyokasuigetsu Performant is a word, but it doesn't mean that :)

Comment: @pst it's one of the things exactly, though I doubt it will result in any increased performance at all.

Comment: something like the .= in php where you just keep on appending stuff to the string and echo it out once you have everything.

Comment: as @Anonymous said, for your purposes, you're not going to see any appreciable increase in performance by doing something like creating a long HTML string containing all your table cells and then setting it as the html of the table row.

Comment: @jackwanders: but as far as best practices is concerned this is the way to go right?

Comment: If you are attempting to append multiple jQuery objects to a single element, then yes, the best practice is to use a single `.append` call with a comma separated list of elements, in the order you want them appended.

Comment: Well talking about the best practices you would surely create `$("<tr>")` and such elements into a variable first, before starting the loop, so you wouldn't have to create it all the time while looping.

Comment: hence why I limited the scope of my comment; I wasn't commenting on his loop.

Comment: Don't repeatedly append stuff to the actual document if you can avoid it. If the comma-separated approach actually builds in a documentFragment first and then appends that, that's the ideal approach.

Answer (score 1):

```
var tr_next = $("<tr>");
var td_contact_fname = $("<td>").attr({"width" : "190px" , "align" : "center"});
var groupby = td_contact_fname.add(td_contact_lname,td_month,td_day,td_email);

$('.abc').each(function(){
    tr_next.append(groupby.clone())
});
```

Edit: don't forget to clone the element;

Comment: might do but you're still appending stuff into the dom on every iteration of the loop.

Comment: as I said the dom will be locked once you are in the loop. so it does not matter.

Answer (score 1):

You can create elements without attaching them to the DOM:

`var $_container = $('<div id="someContainerId" />');`

Now you can loop or do the comma thing or what-have-you without causing reflow every time you add new stuff to the actual container and then append the container, triggering just one reflow rather than a whole bunch.

For non-jQuery approaches I recommend looking up documentFragment.